# Using Moq to Mock an interface still triggers underlying method

Tags: web-services, unit-testing, interface, moq

I have a class that uses a web service that looks roughly like this:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly IAuxilaryService1 auxilaryService1;
    private readonly IAuxilaryService2 auxilaryService2;
    private readonly IAuxilaryService3 auxilaryService3;
    private IWebService service;

    public MyService()
    {
        auxilaryService1 = new AuxilaryService1();
        auxilaryService2 = new AuxilaryService2();
        auxilaryService3 = new AuxilaryService3();
    }

    public void DoSomething(
        string Param1,
        string Param2
        )
    {
        service = new WebService(auxilaryService1, auxilaryService2, auxilaryService3); 

        var response = service.DoSomething(Param1, Param2);
        /* ... */
    }
```

And then a unit test trying to test this doing this:

private Mock webService;

```
    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
       webService = new Mock<IWebService>();
    }

    [Test]
    public void MyService_DoSomethingTest()
    {
        IMyService myService = new MyService();

        webService.Setup(x => x.DoSomething(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
                       .Returns(new Response() { Status = "Foo"});


        myService.DoSomething("Param1", "Param2");

        webService.Verify(x => x.DoSomething(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()));
    }
```

First of all is this a good way to test "MyService" and second of all, for some reason the Interface is not intercepted properly so in my test, even though I do ask for the webService inside myService to return a fake response, the actual instance still gets called and the test fails with a Soap exception. I know Moq needs interfaces or virtual methods, but I provide an interface Mock so why does it not intercept it? Any ideas?

I need to add that I'm testing custom umbraco contour workflow types and I have no control over the constructor. If I change it the project will break.

Comment: why was this downgraded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to test your class, you should *pass* mocked dependency into that class under test. In your case all dependencies are hard coded in `MyService` (they are instantiated in the class). Use dependency injection to provide dependencies:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly IAuxilaryService1 auxilaryService1;
    private readonly IAuxilaryService2 auxilaryService2;
    private readonly IAuxilaryService3 auxilaryService3;
    private IWebService service;

    // constructor injection
    public MyService(IAuxilaryService1 service1,
                     IAuxilaryService2 service2,
                     IAuxilaryService3 service3)
    {
        auxilaryService1 = service1;
        auxilaryService2 = service2;
        auxilaryService3 = service3;
    }

    // pass IWebService into method
    public void DoSomething(string Param1, string Param2, IWebService service)
    {
        this.service = service;                
        var response = service.DoSomething(Param1, Param2);
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

And now how test should look like:

```
private IMyService myService;

[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    IAuxilaryService1 service1 = new Mock<IAuxilaryService1>();
    IAuxilaryService2 service2 = new Mock<IAuxilaryService2>();
    IAuxilaryService3 service3 = new Mock<IAuxilaryService3>();
    myService = new MyService(service1.Object,
                              service2.Object,
                              service3.Object);       
}

[Test]
public void MyService_DoSomethingTest()
{
    // Arrange
    webService = new Mock<IWebService>();

    webService.Setup(x => x.DoSomething(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
              .Returns(new Response() { Status = "Foo"});
    // Act
    myService.DoSomething("Param1", "Param2", webService.Object);
    // Assert
    webService.Verify(x => x.DoSomething(It.IsAny<string>(),It.IsAny<string>()));
}
```

BTW it's strange that you are instantiating webService inside `DoSomething` method and assign webService to class field. Maybe you need webService passed into your class via constructor also?

Comment: That means a lot messier code. I will now have to instantiate all the auxilary services outside my class, and also initialise the webService in each class where it's being used just so that I can pass them as a parameter. Isn't there a way that doesn't require a lot of code duplication?

Comment: @Nick that means clean code. Dependencies should be instantiated outside your class. Class should depend on abstractions instead of implementations.

Comment: Let's assume my service is used in 20 different places.

Now I can no longer do myService = new MyService(); and later myService.DoSomething();. I'll have to initialize all the auxilary services in each class where it's used and initialise the service.

Not sure this is cleaner. It's also a lot of work

Comment: @Nick that is option called [poor man's dependency injection](http://lostechies.com/chadmyers/2009/07/14/just-say-no-to-poor-man-s-dependency-injection/)

Comment: @Nick with dependency injection framework you don't need to instantiate classes manually. And remember, when you are unit-testing some class, that class should be the only real object during test. All other dependencies should be mocked, which is impossible if you create some dependencies in class.

Comment: Ok you're right. I did go with adding a second constructor though, as I don't think it matters if the auxiliary services are initialised at all if the whole service is being mocked

Comment: @Nick just be careful in unit tests - somebody can invoke parameterless constructor and real objects will be created

Answer (score 2):

You're never injecting the mocked instance to `myService`. You could create a constructor to inject the dependency. Something like this

```
  public MyService(IWebService service)
  {
      this.service = service;
  }
```

And then you have to use this constructor on your test.

Comment: Well.. that would work but it means a lot of refactoring of the existing code where this service is used :/

Comment: @Nick: that what you have to do if you want to mock, I'm afraid there is no magic, you're creating a mock but never using it.

Comment: @Nick:BTW: You don't have to change the existing constructor but adding a new one so all code around will still work

Answer (score 2):

The implementation is not using the mocked instance, because of this line:

```
service = new WebService(auxilaryService1, auxilaryService2, auxilaryService3);
```

Welcome to dependency injection. If you want to mock this object, `MyService` need to ask for it rather than make it.

Make your code look like this:

```
private readonly IWebService webService;

public MyService(IWebService webService)
{
  this.webService = webService;
}

public void DoSomething(...)
{
   var response = webService.DoSomething(Param1, Param2);
    /* ... */
}
```

And in your test, you'll need to pass your mock instance to the constructor:

```
IMyService myService = new MyService(webService);
```